# Physics objects not lying flat

Tags: physics

I have made a scene with bowling pins sitting on a plane. The pins are active physics objects with convex hull. The plane is passive. Note how the pins "drop" into the plane, but then settle correctly. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

[image]

I suspect it has something to do with my origins, though not sure what. I've set origin to "Center of mass (volume)". Changing the physics shape to box looks like this:

[image]

Blend file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n2zb78y74c3pdy/bowling-alley.blend?dl=0

Comment: Haven't looked at the file, but it looks like your using a subsurf. That may be causing the bottom to be very slightly rounded. Try selecting any mesh in the center of the bottom of the pin and moving it up a bit, so that it will only sit on the outer edge and see if that helps at all.

Comment: Looks like your convex hull is dropping down into the green box. Try aligning the two shapes. Check the physics of your plane - it should be a static object.

Comment: a) The subsurf modifier has no effect (either removed or applied), b) "Try aligning the two shapes" ... how? I thought the point of a convex hull was it "automatically" wrapped the object? c) The plane is a passive rigid body with sensitivity margin 4cm. Removing this, and also checking "collision margin" on the pin and setting to 0cm appears to fix the issue for convex hull, though the box shape is still in the wrong place so I'm convinced this is a great way to solve the issue.